# ASP.NET API returning strange values to Angular

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular

I appear to be having some issues with my ASP.NET API talking to Angular and I'm not totally sure why. I'm hoping someone can glance at what I've done and look for anything obvious.

In my API Controller I have the following code:

```
// Data Structure to hold results from query
public class MyContainer
    {
        public ulong id;
        public int num;

        public MyContainer(ulong id, int num)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.num = num;
        }
    }


public class MyAPIController : ControllerBase {

        [Route("/Testing")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<MyContainer> GetMethod()
        {
            var x = from r in context.TableOne
                    group r by r.Id into g
                    select new MyContainer(g.Key, g.Count() );

            var y = x.First();
            logger.LogInformation(y.num.ToString());  // This outputs correctly!

            return x.ToList();
        }
}
```

And in Angular, I have the following service:

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

class MyContainer {
    public id: number;
    public num: number;
}

export class MyService {
     ...
     getMethod(): Observable<MyContainer> {
        let url = this.baseUrl + 'Testing';
        let test = this.http.get(url, httpOptions);

        // This outputs an array with the correct number of elements, but they are all blank...
        // Such as [{…}, {…}, {…}], and when expanded, they are empty.
        test.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
        
        return test;
    }
}
```

**Please note, I've added three comments in my code above to help highlight my issues.**

I've just started learning ASP.NET so I imagine I'm missing something obvious.

**What I know works:**

1. The Routing works -- I am able to hit my API's GetMethod() without any problems.
2. My LINQ Database Query -- As mentioned in the second comment, from my Logger in the API Controller I see my API Function successfully queries the database and returns the value I'm expecting. It just doesn't get passed to Angular correctly.

**What I've Tried:**

1. Adding the `[ApiController]` attribute to my API Controller.

   - This actually gives me a weird 400 error, "The input does not contain does not contain any JSON tokens..."?
2. Using a POST instead of a GET.
3. Modifying the data structures used in the return (i.e. trying `List<MyContainer>`)
4. Using raw SQL instead of LINQ.
5. Changing `MyContainer` to use only strings + converting the results in the database query to strings (to see if it could be a serialization issue).

**What I think the Problems Could Be:**

1. ASP.NET/Angular don't like me returning data via my `MyContainer` class.
2. Since I am using the Entity Core framework, it may not like that `MyContainer` is not registered as a "Keyless Entity Type", but it is not giving me any errors so I don't think this is the problem.
3. Every single time I go to test this API function, God sends down cosmic rays in just the right way to hit the electrons storing the API's return result in Angular's memory, thus giving me the correct number of blank elements.

Any help is immensely appreciated! I have a feeling it has to do with me using a custom data type, but again, I don't have any idea why that would be an issue unless its unable to be converted to JSON...

Edit: Using the following libraries

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
```

Comment: Have you looked at the actual data being sent to the browser using your browser's Dev Tools' Network window or Wireshark?

Comment: What is the value of `this.baseUrl`? Does it have a trailing slash?

Comment: @Dai using the Network tab, the data in the response is the same as what gets printed in Angular: ```[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]```. this.baseUrl is indeed just my home url, it does have a trailing slash.

Comment: What JSON serialization library are you using? (e.g. `Newtonsoft.Json` or `System.Text.Json`, or something else?)

Comment: @Dai I'm not explicitly sure which one I'm using, whatever's built into Entity Core I suppose. I also just tried making everything into a String and doing it that way, but again with no luck.

Comment: Entity Framework is only concerned with database access, not JSON serialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your DTO (`MyContainer`) is not serializing its fields. IIRC, by default, most JSON serializers for .NET only serialize public properties, not public fields.

I assume you're using `Newtonsoft.Json`, but it's trivial to convert this to `System.Text.Json`:

The main fix is to change your `MyContainer` DTO to use properties instead of fields. Note that using `JsonProperty` is optional, but I prefer setting explicit names (and don't use `camelCase` for public instance members in .NET, only use `TitleCase`):

```
public class MyContainer
{
    public MyContainer(ulong id, int number)
    {
        this.Id     = id;
        this.Number = num;
    }

    [JsonProperty( "id" )]
    public UInt64 Id { get; }

    [JsonProperty( "num" )]
    public Int32 Number { get; }
}
```

Secondarily, I'd improve your controller action like so, but please read these articles:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/conventions?view=aspnetcore-3.1
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-3.1

```
[ApiController]
public class MyApiController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("/Testing")] // <-- This implicitly allows GET and HEAD, you don't need a separate [HttpGet] attribute.
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, typeof(List<MyContainer>))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetMethod()
    {
        // Do data access asynchronously...
        var groups = await this.context
            .TableOne
            .GroupBy( r => r.Id )
            .Select( grp => new { Id = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count() } )
            .ToListAsync();
            
        // ...but transform the data synchronously:
        List<MyContainer> list = groups
            .Select( g => new MyContainer( g.Id, g.Count ) )
            .ToList();

        return this.OK( list );
    }
}
```

In your TypeScript code, it's generally a better idea to use readonly interfaces rather than classes to represent DTOs because you can *meaningfully* cast deserialized JSON (and object-literals in general) to interfaces, but not meaningfully cast object-literals to classes (as JSON objects don't have function-properties or inheritance anyway):

So change this:

```
class MyContainer {
    public id: number;
    public num: number;
}
```

To this:

```
interface MyContainer {
    readonly id : number;
    readonly num: number;
}
```

Comment: Oh damn that was it! Such a small detail! Thanks for the tip about .NET formatting btw as well :) Thank you so much!

Comment: @Pecans I've updated my answer with suggestions for how to improve your Controller action.

Comment: Wow you seem to know your .NET! I'll go through your suggestions tomorrow and work on them, fried from trying to figure out my original issue all day lol. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Pecans Thank you for the kind words. I lived through the pain of WebForms and WCF, so you kids today have no idea how great you have it now ;)